# How can i make that in the timer my program will do something every second?

Tags: java, android

In the top of MainActivity.java i added:

```
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
```

Then inside the onCreate i did:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });
```

Then in the updateTimerThread:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            long updatedTime = 0L;
            long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;//System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

Now each time i run my program from the start the timer will start from 00:00:00

Now i want to add somehow something that each second to do something.
Not to reset the timer not to pause or stop it to let it keep running but each second i want to do something else in my program.

The problem is how do i check every second to do something ?